# Posting in Facebook with PHP and SDK 5.0 like a page

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

i'm trying to post into a Facebook page that i'm administrator with a php code. The thing is, when i add a post in my personal web page i want to publish it into a company page in Facebook. It's works and i get the post id, but, when i go to Facebook i saw it like a notification that "pepito shares a link with", but it doesn't in the biography wall. )

This is the permission i set 'manage_pages', 'publish_actions', 'pages_manage_instant_articles'.

And this is my code:

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
$fbok = false;
session_start();
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V5_SRC_DIR', 'facebook-sdk-v5/');
require_once 'facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
]);
if(!isset($_GET['error'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        try {
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $requestUserName = $fb->request('GET', '/inmoejemplognu?fields=id,name');
            $batch = [ 'user-profile' => $requestUserName ];
            $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
            //$responses = json_decode($response->getBody());
            $data = [];
            $id = "";
            foreach ($responses as $key => $response) {
              if (!$response->isError()) {
                $data = json_decode($response->getBody());
                if($data->name == "Alquiler Vivienda"){
                    $id = $data->id;
                }       
              }
            }
            echo $id;
            $fbok = true;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $permissions = ['manage_pages', 'publish_actions', 'pages_manage_instant_articles']; // optional
            $callback    = 'http://pablognu.tigrimigri.com/login-callback.php';
            $loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
            header('Location: '. $loginUrl);
        }
    } else {
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $permissions = ['manage_pages', 'publish_actions', 'pages_manage_instant_articles']; // optional
        $callback    = 'http://pablognu.tigrimigri.com/login-callback.php';
        $loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
        header('Location: '. $loginUrl);
    }
}
if($fbok){
    echo "Podemos publicar";
            $linkData = [
              'link' => 'http://www.google.es',
              'message' => 'Un ejemplo de publicacion',
             ];
            try {
              $response = $fb->post('/'.$id.'/feed', $linkData, $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }
            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
            echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
//} else {
//  echo "No se ha autorizado el acceso para publicar en facebook";
}
```

?>

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post "as Page" (which is what you want to achieve, i assume), you have to use `publish_pages`, not `publish_actions`. And you have to use a Page Token. The docs are very specific about that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed#publish

About Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/